# How do I split sorted values into 2 different arrays from an array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript example where I have an array **articleBody** where I am trying to sort the values from the key "type" I have the sort function ready as shown:

Array:

```
var articleBody = [
    {
        "type": "code"  
    },{
        "type": "video"  
    },{
        "type": "code"  
    },{
        "type": "video"  
    },{
        "type": "code"  
    },{
        "type": "video"  
    }
]
```

The sort function:

```
articleBody.sort(function(a, b) {
    var typeA = a.type.toUpperCase(); 
    var typeB = b.type.toUpperCase(); 
    if (typeA < typeB) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (typeA > typeB) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

How do I get a subarray with typeA and one for typeB?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: And what exactly you are trying to do... Do you want one array per comparison?

Comment: Hi @LucaKiebel yes I want each type in their own array

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve and why are you sorting the array for that?

Comment: @LucaKiebel I need to have each value in their own array so that I can show only the array based on value a or value b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply trying to obtain an array filtered by the type, then a simple function like below would work:

```
/**
 * @param {Array} arr - the array being filtered
 * @param {String} type - value of the type being sought
 * @returns array filtered by type
 */
function subArrayByType(arr, type) {
    return arr.filter(el=>el.type == type);
}

const codes = subArrayByType(articleBody, 'code');
const videos = subArrayByType(articleBody, 'video');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function splitByPropVal(array, prop) {
    return array.reduce(function(acc, item) {
      if (acc[item[prop]] === undefined) acc[item[prop]] = [];
      acc[item[prop]].push(item);
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }

splitByPropVal(articleBody, 'type');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop approach and an object and take the type as criterium for pushing.

```js
var articleBody = [{ type: "code" }, { type: "video" }, { type: "code" }, { type: "video" }, { type: "code" }, { type: "video" }],
    types = {};

articleBody.forEach(o => (types[o.type] = types[o.type] || []).push(o));

console.log(types);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method returns a copy of your array with all elements, that match a certain predicate.

```
const typeA = articleBody.filter(a => a.type === 'code');
const typeB = articleBody.filter(a => a.type === 'video');
```